# Perspective image transformation in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

What the best way to make this kind of transformation: I have 4 pairs of coordinates, and I need to put the corners of my image exactly to them?
Like in photoshop, when you in free transform mode and moving corners of the image while holding ctrl.
[image]

Something like that.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to "free transform" like in Photoshop?  Or are you doing it automatically based on the coordinates you already have?

Comment: At the begining only fixed coordinates. But later may be free transform too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the Flash 10 `drawTriangles()` method, then [this link](http://zehfernando.com/2010/the-best-drawplane-distortimage-method-ever/) will provide you with a great explanation of what you are trying to do, with some well documented functioning code. The code is very similar to the solution that romamik provided, however, you will need to calculate the correct `t` value of the `uvtData` to get it to render correctly:

To summarize from that link:

- Calculate the center point of the rectangle you are trying to draw
- Get the distance between each point and the center
- Calculate the ratio between the diagonals
- use the formula `(1/point_distance)*ratio` to calculate perspective distortion for each point -- project into a faux 3d space (aka "magic" as the author of the post calls it)

That should produce the effect you are looking for.

If you can't use `drawTriangles()` then [this link](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage) provides an alternative, however it wont produce as good of results as the `drawTriangles()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use graphics.drawTriangles.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS84753F1C-5ABE-40b1-A2E4-07D7349976C4.html

This code should do what you need (untested)

```
graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData);
graphics.drawTriangles( 
   Vector.<Number>([10,10, 100,10, 10,100, 100,100]), 
   Vector.<int>([0,1,2, 1,3,2]),
   Vector.<Number>([0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1])
);
```

Comment: Also see http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage for an pre-`drawTriangles` implementation

Comment: And i think that the last `Vector.<Number>` (uvtData) needs a `t` component to display a 3D-ish perspective correctly. where `t = focalLength/(focalLength + z);` though in this case you probably want to calculate `t` differently

Comment: Author is saying about pairs of coordinates, so I think he don't have z coordinate and thus he can't calculate t. And it's ok to not specify t.

Comment: you *need* to calculate `t` if you want the faux 3d-effect (where it looks like the "w" of is closer than the "s" in "stackoverflow". its okay to not specify `t` however, you will get results that look like this: http://wonderfl.net/c/cdon

Comment: What 32bitkid said is correct. You *need* to specify T if you need an actual perspective distortion. If you don't, you'll still see pixels drawn and all that, but it doesn't mean it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DistortImage class](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage) ported from the old 3D engine Sandy. A cleaner way would be the make use of `rotateX` and `rotateY` but it would require some mathematical pain!